# How to interpret results from diff-in-diff binary treatment

Tags: econometrics, interpretation, difference-in-difference

I ran a dynamic diff-in-diff , of the form

$$ y_{it} = \gamma_{i} + \lambda_{t} + \delta T_{it} + \epsilon_{it} $$

y :  log(lead concentration) , log concentration of lead in drinking water.

$\gamma_{i}$  :  denotes *city* and

$\lambda_{t}$  denotes *year* fixed effects,

$T_{it}$ is the treatment dummy variable, indexing the $i$ cities affected by the policy/intervention during periods $t$, 0 otherwise.

These are the results

```
  x      y      y_min  y_max Group
  2018  -4.11  -4.986 -3.229 After 
  2017  -3.40  -4.015 -2.775 After 
  2016  -2.96  -3.292 -2.618 After 
  2015  -2.08  -2.406 -1.758 After 
  2014  -0.993 -1.328 -0.659 After 
  2013   0     0      0      Before
  2012   0.211 -0.148 0.569  Before
  2011   0.125 -0.276 0.526  Before
  2010   0.056 -0.565 0.677  Before
  2009   0.642 0.0100 1.273  Before
  2008   0.429 -0.241 1.099  Before
```

[image]

I am not sure how to interpret these results. Need help understanding the temporal nature of these coefficients. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated, Bridgeport. Your data look like something happened at around 2013, but why are you clumping together the lead levels from different cities? I would have thought that the real-world causes of lead in drinking water would lead to step changes in individual cities that would be more interesting to me than the average or levels among selected cities.

Comment: @MichaelLew, Thanks Michael. Good question. This is a state level data. So cities within that state. There was a law suit in 2013-2014 and the outcome of the judgment forced corporations to take corrective actions. So these are samples from different households across cities within the state.

Comment: Thanks Bridgeport, I'm happy to hear that the state is taking action to deal with the disgraceful number of contaminated water systems. However, that doesn't seem to me to motivate an analysis that groups together the different cities. The increase in error bar width as the mean goes down might reflect an increase in varibiility on log[Pb] as the values go down, or it might reflect some cities not having decreasing levels. Perhaps plot the individual city data rather than averages.